# Artificially censored regressors in linear model

Tags: regression, censoring

I am running a linear regression looking at the effect of long term rainfall averages and rainfall shocks on district welfare (Y). I have measures of rainfall long term averages (rain_lt) as well as measures of rainfall level in the year preceding the survey where welfare is computed (Lag1_rain). In one of the specifications I define the rainfall shock as the difference between the year-specific level and the long term average (Lag1_rain-rain_lt), which I call Lag1_rain_diff. Since I am interested in seeing what is the effect of much higher rain than usual (flooding) as well as much lower rain than usual (drought), I split Lag1_rain_diff into two different variables:

1) Lag1_rain_diff_flood = Lag1_rain-rain_lt if Lag1_rain>=rain_lt, 
   Lag1_rain_diff_flood = 0 otherwise

2) Lag1_rain_diff_drought  = -(Lag1_rain-rain_lt)  if Lag1_rain

And the obtained linear regression specification is the following:

Y = rain_lt + Lag1_rain_diff_flood + Lag1_rain_diff_drought  + Controls + error

I was wondering whether the introduction of two regressors that are artificially censored at 0 introduces any bias in the regression, and in the case they do, how to redefine the specification in order to avoid the issue.

Thank you very much in advance!